# Mysql query in bash script fails if bash script is executed as non root user

Tags: bash, mysql-connector

I have a very simple bash script file for ex:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER="myuser"
PASS="mypass"
author="tester"

whoami >> /tmp/log
echo $author >> /tmp/log
cmdu=`/usr/bin/mysql -D mydb -s -u $USER -p$PASS -e "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$author'"`
echo $cmdu >> /tmp/log
echo "ended" >> /tmp/log
```

If I run this file as root I get output in /tmp/log:

```
root
tester
2987
ended
```

My problem is that if I run this script as another, non root user (for ex. kola) mysql query fails with error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

and output in /tmp/log is:

```
kola
tester

ended
```

Can you pls help what to fix to make mysql query run? I tried many things so far:

```
usermod -a -G mysql kola
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql
```

created `kola` mysql user in `mysql.user` and granted all privileges

In production I need apache user to be able to run similar .sh file with mysql query statement in it and it fails.

Thanks in advance!

Ivanhou

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Your `chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql` is wrong and creates a serious security exploit.  Add the ouput of `ls -la /var/run/mysqld/` to the question.

Comment: Call in a sysadmin to fix this; it's not a developer's job (it's not a matter of writing code and is categorically off-topic here). Having _ever_ run that `chmod` means your system can no longer be trusted (even if the files that had their permissions changed still match their original hashes, you don't know if an attacker temporarily changed one of them to install an exploit elsewhere and then changed the executable back to cover their tracks).

Comment: @LjmDullaart, ... Let's say the socket _isn't_ writable by the mysql group. That just raises more questions, about whether the packaging installed it correctly and it was broken afterwards or if some other ill-advised manual chown was run. The _safe_ thing is to get back to the state the package developer intended wholesale, not patching around individual problems as they're found -- _particularly_ when you don't have eyes on the ground of someone with a working knowledge of the security model &c.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right; the question would be better suited for the Unix/Linux part of SE.

Comment: @LjmDullaart you are totally right. I would never use chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql in production, but in my private dev environment set in the running docker container with no network seemed harmless. Permission changes are gone after stopping the container.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it adding host into the mysql statement.

```
cmdu=`/usr/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -D mydb -s -u $USER -p$PASS -e "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$author'"`
```

Comment: There are several bad-practice / dangerous examples inside this one line. Due to the lack of double quotes around the `USER` and `PASS` variables, usernames and passwords with spaces can inject extra arguments into the mysql command line; a value of `author` like `evil' or 1=1 or username='` can perform SQL injection (see [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)); and command line arguments (unlike environment variables, which are restricted to the same user or root in modern times) are globally visible and thus unsafe to pass passwords on.

Comment: (A process can obscure its command line arguments after it finishes starting, but there's a window before process startup is complete where they're visible, so while that safety measure is better than nothing it's not something to be relied on).